# Redux router - how to replay state after refresh?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

I have a multi-step form application, and I'm struggling with getting my head around how I can save my redux state and replay it after a refresh for example? Going back/forward in the app works as expected, but after a browser refresh, my previous state is empty. Ideally I'd like to be able to save prior state in session storage relating to a path, so that I can replay later, but I'm not seeing how I can do that easily. Has anyone done anything like this and can provide some pointers? Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use a single-page app framework within a multiple-page context. To make the two play nicer together, you could look into making your own middleware that synchronizes state to and from `localStorage` to create an app that appears to not have lost any state after a refresh/page navigation.

1. Similar to the way that [redux-logger](https://github.com/fcomb/redux-logger) logs [both the previous and next states](https://github.com/fcomb/redux-logger/blob/master/src/index.js#L48), I'd probably start by plugging in a middleware at the beginning (`localStorageLoad`) and end (`localStorageDump`) of the `createStoreWithMiddleware` function creation (right before `redux-logger`):

```js
// store/configureStore.js

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(
    localStorageLoad, thunk, promise, localStorageDump, logger
)(createStore);
```

2. Then fire an initial action right when you initialize your app to load stored state before your app renders:

```js
// index.js

const store = configureStore();

store.dispatch({ type: 'INIT' });

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The `localStorageLoad` would handle the `INIT` action and dispatch some sort of `SET_STATE` action, which would contain a payload with the state that was previously saved in `localStorage`.

```js
// middleware/localStorageLoad.js

export default store => next => action => {
    const { type } = action;
    if (type === 'INIT') {
        try {
            const storedState = JSON.parse(
                localStorage.getItem('YOUR_APP_NAME')
            );
            if (storedState) {
                store.dispatch({
                    type: 'RESET_STATE',
                    payload: storedState
                });
            }
            return;
        } catch (e) {
            // Unable to load or parse stored state, proceed as usual
        }
    }

    next(action);
}
```

Then, add a reducer which replaces the state with that payload, effectively rebooting the app as it was previously.

3. To complete the loop, you'd need a `localStorageDump` middleware that comes at the end of the chain that saves each reduced state object into `localStorage`. Something like this:

```js
// middleware/localStorageDump.js

export default store => next => action => {
    const state = store.getState();
    localStorage.setItem('YOUR_APP_NAME', JSON.stringify(state));
    next(action);
}
```

Just an idea, haven't actually tried it. Hope that helps get you started towards a solution.

Comment: Perfect, this looks along the right lines. For some reason I was hung up on using routing rather than thinking middleware. Will give it a go, but its a good starting point either way, thanks!

Comment: Sure, good luck. The nice part about leaning on redux for this is that you end up with all these pieces that are just pure functions. You could easily unit test all of the above code before you even integrate it into your app.

Comment: I found this very useful and I implemented something that works starting with the solution proposed here.  The final solution had a few departures from the suggestions here that I thought I should share.

First, I didn't use the "INIT" method to acquire the initial state.  Instead, I simply loaded the initial state when creating the store.  This might be against the rules, but it makes sense to me.  It's essentially the code localStorageLoad.  

Next, I used sessionStorage.  It's a nitpick, but once the browser is shutdown and restarted, I'd prefer to start over.  I'm running out of room...

Comment: I did use the middleware concept for saving state to the sessionStorage and that is a really sweet solution.  My setup looks like this:

`const middleware = applyMiddleware(..., sessionStorageSave);`

My sessionStorageSave:

`export default store => next => action => {
    next(action);
    const state = store.getState();
    let newState = {};
    for (var key in state) {
        if( state.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
            if (state[key].toJS) {
                newState[key] = state[key].toJS();
            }
        }
    }

    sessionStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(newState));
}`

Comment: Sorry my code looks so bad!  The key in my code is that I had to call next() first before saving state.  That way state was updated before the save.

Answer (score 4):

You can't store state on refresh this is normal. Typically you store these inside cookies or web storage.

- Cookies are synced between browser, server  and are set on every request you perform.
- [Localstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) gives you up to 5MB to store data in and never gets send with the request.

Redux:

1. Set localstorage properties when filling in form. (be sure to clean it when complete)
2. Refresh the page with an incomplete form.
3. When react mounts your `Form` component, use `componentWillMount` method to read the `localstorage` and `dispatch` the data to a reducer
4. The reducer updates the redux-state which in turn updates the component with the properties you got from localstorage.

If you use redux to store form data dispatch the properties of localstorage.

If not read the localstorage inside the `Form` component and set the initial values.

Hope this helps !

Comment: I know this is normal behaviour, but I was hoping for some ability to save my redux state on router change into sessionStorage for that particular route, and then update state in one go. I know redux-router saves the route information into my state, I was just hoping to do this app wide rather than at a component level.

Comment: Oh so you mean you want to save the state of an unfinished form when you transition to another route in your app? I misunderstood I thought you meant to restore the state when a user `closed a tab` and `revisited` the app.

This actually has nothing to do with router transition but rather the internal state of the redux store. You might want to take a look at https://github.com/erikras/redux-form

This saves the form state inside the redux store. So even when you transition back the state will still be the same in the form unless you said otherwise and passed the correct props.

Comment: No, basically when the user transitions from A to B, I'd like to store the state as of A so it can be reloaded if they go back to B (refresh etc) based on the URL. But I want to do this app wide, rather than per component, if possible. Basically to allow hot loading, without refactoring everything to use webpack (using browserify at the moment).