# Why am I losing my ReactJS state?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS, but I have a simple use case: I have a login form that sets the user's state (full name, etc.) and then I use the React Router to browserHistory.push('/') back to the home page. I can confirm that if I stay on the login page that my states actually get saved, however when I go back to the homepage, and into my "parent" component (App.js) and run this before the render method:

`console.log(this.state) // this returns null`

It always returns true. My constructor is not even doing anything with the state. If I put a log in the constructor on my App.js parent component I can verify that the page is not actually being reloaded, that the component is only mounted once (at least the constructor on App.js is only called once during the whole homepage > login > homepage lifecycle). Yet again, the state seems to be removed after changing pages.

What simple thing am I missing?

Edit: some code, trying to simplify it:

```
// LoginForm.js
//Relevant method
  handleSubmit() {
   this.login(this.state.username, this.state.password, (success) => {
      if (!success)
      {
        this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false })
        this.setState({ loginError: true })
        return
      }

      this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true })

      browserHistory.push('/') // I can verify it gets here and if at this point I console.log(this.isLoggedIn) I return true
    })
  }

    // App.js
    class App extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log('hello')
      }

      render() {
        const { props } = this
        console.log(this.state) // returns null
    return (
    <div>
      <AppBar style={{backgroundColor: '#455a64'}}
              title="ADA Aware"
              showMenuIconButton={false}>
        <LoginBar/>
      </AppBar>
      <div>
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </div>
  )}
    //Part of my routes.js
    export default (
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={HomePage}/>
        <Route path="/login" component={LoginForm}/>
        <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage}/>
      </Route>
    );
```

Comment: How about sharing the code instead of trying to describe it?

Comment: Which state?  How many components are we talking about?  How are you updating it? (Share some code!)

Comment: I added code, let me know if this helps, tried to get it to the relevant bits

Answer (score 0):

Where you call `handleSubmit()`, what component calls it?
If it is `<LoginForm>` or `<LoginBar>` or something like this, your `this.` means that component, non `<App>`.

To set parent's state (`<App>` in your case) you should pass to child a property with a handler function (for example `onLogin={this.handleAppLogin.bind(this)}`) so your child must call this prop (`this.props.onLogin(true)`) and handler in the `<App>` will set App's state: `handleAppLogin(isLoggedIn) { this.setState({isLoggedIn}); }`

But for the "global" state values such as login state, access tokens, usernames etc, you better shoud use Redux or some other Flux library.

Comment: {props.children}

This renders the child elements. I'm thinking global elements do need some something else to handle it as as far as I understand state shouldn't flow "up" to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

This was a closed issue router project and discussed in many SO articles:

- https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1094
- https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux/issues/358
- [Redux router - how to replay state after refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34038726/redux-router-how-to-replay-state-after-refresh)

However, it is persistent real world need.  I guess the pattern of how to handle this is based on Redux and/or browser storage.